# Android: How to show current location of multiple devices?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, location, position

For my master thesis I have to implement the following:

An app with different tabs where Google Maps should be displayed in one tab. The goal is to display the current position of a device. This is to be implemented with up to 5 devices, where each device in the app sees the position of the other. This is to be followed by a distance measurement through Bluetooth.

What I have so far:

- Display of Google Maps in one tab
- current position from a device where the app is started right now

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W44UU.png)

**My question is:
How do I add the position of each of the other devices? If all 5 devices open the app, then everyone should be able to see everyone.
Should I create a Database where the positions are stored and than fetch these positions and set a marker?**

Does each device need its own google account? Do the devices need to be unlocked with an ID?

I would be grateful for any help.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.thesis">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_tab_ansicht.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.thesis;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    
    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
    import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
    import com.example.thesis.fragment.AllgemeinFragment;
    import com.example.thesis.fragment.AnsichtFragment;
    import com.example.thesis.fragment.PositionFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        private static final int TAG_CODE_PERMISSION_LOCATION = 255;
        TabLayout tabLayout;
        ViewPager viewPager;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
            viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    
            ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    
            // Tab Überschriften
            arrayList.add("Ansicht");
            arrayList.add("Position");
            arrayList.add("Allgemein");
    
            //viewpager
            prepareViewPager(viewPager, arrayList);
    
            //setup mit viewpager
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {
                                                          Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                                                          Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION },
                                                  TAG_CODE_PERMISSION_LOCATION);
            }
    
        }
    
        private void prepareViewPager(ViewPager viewPager, ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
            //main adapter initialisieren
            MainAdapter adapter = new MainAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            //fragments initialisieren
            AnsichtFragment ansichtFragment = new AnsichtFragment();
            PositionFragment positionFragment = new PositionFragment();
            AllgemeinFragment allgemeinFragment = new AllgemeinFragment();
    
            for (int i = 0; i<arrayList.size(); i++)
            {
                //Bundle initialisieren
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                //put String
                bundle.putString("title", arrayList.get(i));
                //argument setzen
                allgemeinFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                positionFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                ansichtFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    
                //add Fragments
                if (i ==0) {
                    //Fragment hinzufügen
                    adapter.addFragment(ansichtFragment, arrayList.get(i));
                    //neues fragment definieren
                    ansichtFragment = new AnsichtFragment();
                } else if (i==1) {
                    adapter.addFragment(positionFragment, arrayList.get(i));
                    //neues fragment definieren
                    positionFragment = new PositionFragment();
                } else if (i==2) {
    
                    adapter.addFragment(allgemeinFragment, arrayList.get(i));
                    //neues fragment definieren
                    allgemeinFragment = new AllgemeinFragment();
                }
            }
            //Adapter setzen
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    
        }
    
        private class MainAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    
            //Arraylist initialisieren
            ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    
            //Konstruktor
            public void addFragment (Fragment fragment, String title) {
                // Titel hinzufügen
                arrayList.add(title);
                // Fragment hinzufügen
                fragmentList.add(fragment);
            }
    
            public MainAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }
    
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                //Fragment position hinzufügen
                return fragmentList.get(position);
            }
    
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                //Rückgabe der FragmentList Größe
                return fragmentList.size();
            }
    
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                //Rückgabe ArrayList position
                return arrayList.get(position);
            }
        }
    }
```

AnsichtFragment.java

```
    package com.example.thesis.fragment;
    
    import android.Manifest;
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Looper;
    import android.provider.Settings;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
    import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import com.example.thesis.R;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
    
    /**
     * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
     * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
     * {@link MainFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
     * to handle interaction events.
     * Use the {@link MainFragment#newInstance} factory method to
     * create an instance of this fragment.
     */
    public class AnsichtFragment extends Fragment  {
        MapView mMapView;
        private GoogleMap googleMap;
        private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
    
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            //View initialisieren
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_ansicht, container, false);
    
            mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map);
            mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately
    
            //location client initialisieren
            fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
    
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity()
                    , Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //When permission is granted
                //call method
                getCurrentLocation();
            }else {
                //when permission is not granted
                //reguest permission
                requestPermissions(new String[] {
                                                          Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                                                          Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION },
                                                  100);
            }
    
            try {
                MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
            mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                    googleMap = mMap;
                    // For showing a move to my location button
                    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    
                   getCurrentLocation();
    
                }
            });
            return rootView;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            //check condiition
            if(requestCode == 100 && (grantResults.length > 0) &&
                    (grantResults[0] + grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
                //when permission are granted
                //call method
                getCurrentLocation();
            }else {
                //when permission denied, display toast
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    
        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        private void getCurrentLocation() {
            //location manager initialisieren
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            //check conditions
            if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
                || locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
                //if location service is enabled
                //get last location
                fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                        //Location initialisieren
                        Location location = task.getResult();
                        LatLng currentPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                        //check condition
                        if (location != null) {
                            //when not null, set latitude 
                            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentPosition).title("Standort").snippet("Aktuelle Position"));
                            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(currentPosition).zoom(12).build();
                            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                        }else {
                            //when location is null
                            //initialize location result
                            LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest()
                                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                                    .setInterval(10000)
                                    .setFastestInterval(1000)
                                    .setNumUpdates(1);
    
                            //Initialize location call back
                            LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback(){
                                @Override
                                public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                                    //initialize location
                                    Location location1 = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                                    //Set latutude 
                                    location1.getLatitude();
                                    //set longitude
                                    location1.getLongitude();
                                }
                            };
                            // Request Location
                            fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest
                                    , locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }else {
                // when location service is not enabled
                //open location settings
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)
                                      .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            mMapView.onResume();
            super.onResume();
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mMapView.onDestroy();
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onLowMemory() {
            super.onLowMemory();
            mMapView.onLowMemory();
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Google location sharing would require each device to have accts; for database checkout Firebase which is free for small apps.  When using external DB (such as firebase) be sure user understands your app is sharing their location; google location sharing makes this clear in the actions the user takes to allow it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, If you want to share data between devices you will probably better off use a DB, as mentioned in the comments ,for fast projects firebase is recommended, easy to install and use.
You will probably need to save the long and lat of the locations of each user and pull it from each device that want to see other people locations.

You may refer to this:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map-with-marker

Maybe try with markers if its enough for your project:

```
    @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    LatLng myLocation = new LatLng(<LAT_FROM_DB>, <LONG_FROM_DB>);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(myLocation )
        .title("My Other User"));
}
```

Good luck with the master thesis.